# LuaLaTeX, Babel and ngerman: Spurious and wrong hyphens appear in a particular word in the middle of a line for no reason

Tags: luatex, babel, hyphenation

Compile this MWE with LuaLaTex:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}

Es sind pri­vat­sphä­reschützende Lösungen vorgeschlagen worden.

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image: Result]

The problem is obvious: The hyphens in "privatsphäreschützende" should not be there.

Please note that the problem does not occur with XeLaTeX. Due to other packages which are not part of this MWE but which I am using in my project, I am sticked to LuaLaTeX + Babel.

How can I fix this problem?

Moreover, I spotted this problem by luck in a 300 page long document. Is there any way to make sure that there are no other problems of this kind? I.e., does anybody know what triggers this error and for what I should look out in my source code?

Version information:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019 Gentoo Linux)  (format=lualatex 2020.2.18)  23 FEB 2020 18:34
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2019-05-18 2.97 luaotfload entry point
Lua module: luaotfload-init 2019-05-18 2.97 luaotfload submodule / initialization
Lua module: lualibs 2019-05-18 2.65 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2019-05-18 2.65 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended collection.
Lua module: luaotfload-log 2019-05-18 2.97 luaotfload submodule / logging
Lua module: luaotfload-parsers 2019-05-18 2.97 luaotfload submodule / filelist
Lua module: luaotfload-configuration 2019-05-18 2.97 luaotfload submodule / config file reader
Lua module: luaotfload-loaders 2019-05-18 2.97 luaotfload submodule / callback handling
Lua module: luaotfload-database 2019-05-18 2.97 luaotfload submodule / database
Lua module: luaotfload-colors 2019-05-18 2.97 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-resolvers 2019-05-18 2.97 luaotfload submodule / resolvers
Lua module: luaotfload-features 2019-05-18 2.97 luaotfload submodule / features
Lua module: luaotfload-letterspace 2019-05-18 2.97 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-auxiliary 2019-05-18 2.97 luaotfload submodule / auxiliary functions
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
File: size10.clo 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
Package: babel 2019/05/04 3.31 The Babel package
File: switch.def 2019/05/04 3.31 Babel switching mechanism
Language: ngerman 2018/12/08 v2.11 German support for babel (post-1996 orthography)
Language: ngermanb 2018/12/08 v2.11 German support for babel (post-1996 orthography)
File: babel.def 2019/05/04 3.31 Babel common definitions
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with LuaLaTeX, `LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 3`, `babel 2020/02/14 3.40`, `ngerman 2018/12/08 v2.11`.

Comment: @moewe I assumed and anticipated that. Probably, because you have a more recent LaTeX2e or Babel version. Unfortunately, I have no control over the version of the packages. So I need a workaround.

Comment: Sorry but beside saying "update" there is not much one can do. It is quite difficult and time consuming to setup a test system with exactly your versions and to investigate this. Do you really expect us to spent hours to investigate a bug for which we know that it has been corrected already?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Of course, I do not expect this. That would be very egotistical. I hoped, that somebody would knew what the problem is, because he/she also encountered it in the past, too. Moreover, I hoped that a quick-and-dirty fix like putting the word into a hbox would do the trick.

Comment: @nagmat84 You should be able to fix the problem by deleting the soft hyphens: Replace "pri­vat­sphä­reschützende" with "privatsphäreschützende".

Comment: To allow hyphenation, you can use `\-` instead.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger What do you mean by soft hyphens? I have no hyphens in my source code.

Comment: A soft hyphen is a unicode codepoint which basically means the same as `\-`: It is invisible, but it gives a hint to the reading program that this is a possible breakpoint. In your input, there are such soft hyphens at the locations where LuaLaTeX inserts the real hyphens.

Comment: @nagmat84 yes you have, the string `pri­vat­sphä­reschützende` has three U+00ad characters

Comment: @MarcelKrüger and DavidCarlisle: Guys, you are awesome. Indeed, that did the trick. I have no idea how these unicode charpoints flit into my source code. I have never typed them by intention. (Maybe a copy and paste error or an not-so-clever feature of my editor.) Now, I will check with a hex editor, if there are others, too.

Comment: Sorry, for this stupid question which has nothing to do with LaTeX. I feel embarrassed.

Comment: @nagmat84 You can add `\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{^^ad}{\HERE}` in your preamble to trigger an error when it appears somewhere.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger or presumably use `\-` instead of `\HERE` and leave them there?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That would be better if they were inserted on purpose, but if nagmat84 didn't even know about them I would recommend to let LuaTeX take care of proper hyphenation. Otherwise they would also have to add additional hyphenation points for "pri­vat­sphä­reschützende`".